# how to replace user control panel with old version in settings

Tags: configuration, user-management

have the proper 'user and groups' installed from LXQt to replace that useless vestigal wart that currently is the 'user accounts' cp.  how to i replace the cp app so i can just go to system settings to find it and don't have to use dash to find it all the time?

TL;DR want to click 'users & groups' from system settings instead of using dash and replace anemic 'user accounts' cp.  how do i do it?

EDIT:  made mistake originally.  said gnome-system-tools, meant LXQt.  :P

Comment: You could modify the "**Exec=**" entry in */usr/share/applications/unity-user-accounts-panel.desktop* Or use compound X "Lock to Launcher"

Comment: okay.  i'll give the modification a shot.  thanks.  quick question though, why are there two execs?  forgive me, i'm a CLI twerp.  the GUI is unfamiliar ground.

Comment: @stumblebee  Nope.  don't got it.  :P

Comment: You mention LXQt but what is the rest of your system? Including the outpu of `echo $DESKTOP_SESSION $XDG_SESSION_TYPE`, `uname -a`, and `lsb_release -a` in your question may help.

Comment: oh! yeah!  apologies!  duh... running Ubuntu 16 LTS in this case and Gnome 3. :facepalm: